# Workflow job of pasting a URL in a hyperlink field, how to have the name/description appear instead of long url?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, workflow-lookup

Follow up to my previous Workflow thread that now works.

When the workflow 'updates the item in current item' and pastes the url correctly (long, complete url) I would like to have the 'description' showing up and not the  long URL, by description I mean the below. the field it is inserting is Encoded Absolute URL

[image]

Comment: @eric alexander I disagree this is a duplicate. The previous question was not able to successfully render a hyperlink and had additional requirements. The OP here is rendering a URL but needs an additional step to add the description to display instead of the URL. Not sure how to request to reopen.

Comment: In your workflow, set the URL equal to a variable. In the String Builder, construct your URL then add a comma and the text you'd like to appear in place of the URL. (e.g. "[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%][%Variable:NewSiteURL%], View Page" View Page will show in place of URL